# BizTalk 2010 Deployment Error. Failed to Add Resource(s)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

I'm building a BizTalk 2010 Application in VS 2010.  Everything had been working great until this morning when I got an error on deployment.  The error is:

> Failed to add resource(s).  Change requests failed for some resources.  BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed to complete end type change request.  Could not save the log to HTML file "C:\Users\BizTalkDeveloper\AppData\Local\Temp\BT\PID7452\BizTalkAssembly\Update.log".  Exception '', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. '', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character".

At first, I thought this was a permissions issue but I'm logged in as a user who is an admin on the machine AND has full control access of that respective AppData folder.  I'm pretty sure that VS creates the BT (and the following path) dynamically at deployment time because I can't find any part of that path after Temp when I look up the path itself.

I've been stumped with this for a few days and I am just out of ideas right now.  If anybody had any suggestions or ideas they could throw my way, I'd really REALLY appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by updating the version number on each project involved with the application and then re-deploying.

While this got the solution to work, I would still like to know, if anybody knows, what went wrong or what would be another way to solve it.  Side note, I did try to uninstall the original version of the DLLs and then redeploy but that didn't work either.

Comment: This worked for us too. Just one of the assemblies refused to deploy, with exactly this error. You're my hero for today.

The below answer may also work (de/re-registering the offending assemblies from the GAC. A couple of other possible solutions are here:

**[MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/74b4cee1-7ae2-41a5-bb53-3bde8fdd8eb1/)** regarding a duplicated port in another assembly, and here:

**[Q&A MSDN](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/2c962933-5ebd-40da-8a1b-5be7cb11c5d6)** - which confirms refreshing  the GAC.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and the error was in a receive location name. Export the bindings, then check the XML for "well-formedness". In my case, the error was like this:

```
<ReceiveLocation Name="In.ShowInvoice&#x1F;_FILE">
```

In BizTalk Admin console, just edit the name and export bindings again until the XML is well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another BizTalk server available, you could try deploying your application there to see if it works in a different environment. Have you tried deploying a *subset* of your assemblies?

> I did try to uninstall the original version of the dlls

What exactly did you try? E.g., have you undeployed and uninstalled the BizTalk application, then checked for remains in the GAC (.NET v2/v4)? I believe that should have been thorough enough.

---

I recall this `System.Xml.XmlException` could occur in BizTalk 2006 when trying to update an assembly while it is still referenced by an existing port.

Deleting the port or at least the dependency (i.e. chosing *pass-thru* adapter) should make the deploy work correctly; afterwards, do not forget to reconfigure the modified port…

If multiple references are in place, then perhaps it might be easier or quicker to just export the bindings, delete all ports, update your assemblies and finally import your bindings again.

Answer (score 0):

There is default application in Biztalk Admin Console. It would be most probably: "BizTalk Application 1". Go to resource section and see if your application resources are there. If they are there remove them and deploye again

Answer (score 0):

Also try deleting the related binding files from this directory:
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\Deployment\BindingFiles\

As per: https://www.tallan.com/blog/2014/08/12/solution-to-common-biztalk-deployment-errors-in-visual-studio/